# How can I keep the date format in a Word replacement?

Tags: excel, vba, date

I'm replacing some tags in a Word document, some of these replacements involve dates, however, when the code makes the replacement, it keeps the date format shown in the formula bar eg. `2/21/2022`, when actually in the cell the date is `21-Feb-2022`, I really need to keep the format that I have in the cell, but I cannot find any way to keep or modify the date format.

Above the part of the code involved

```
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=Ubicación, ReadOnly:=False)   'Open Template
                            
For CustCol = 1 To 20 'Move Through 9 Columns 
    TagName = Sheets("MX-2022").Cells(4, CustCol).Value 'Tag Name
    TagName.Select
    TagValue = Sheets("MX-2022").Cells(Found.Row, CustCol).Value 'Tag Value

    With WordDoc.Content.Find   
        .Text = TagName
        .Replacement.Text = TagValue

        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'Find & Replace all instances
    End With
Next CustCol
```

I'm open to any solution, even if it involves adding an apostrophe to changing the date as text, as long as I'm able to go back to the date format (because yes, I also need to keep it as date for other uses appart from the replacement)

Comment: Try `Text` property instead of `Value` property, e.g. `Sheets("MX-2022").Cells(4, CustCol).Text`

Answer (score 1):

- The [Range.Value property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value) returns the numeric value of the date.
- The [Range.Text property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.text) Returns the formatted text of the date.

---

Alternatively you can use the [Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) to format the numeric value of the date:

```
Format$(YourRange.Value, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

This has the advantage/disatvantage that if anyone changes the format in the Excel cell it is fix in Word. You might want or not want the Word format changing with the Excel cell format.
If you use `Format()` it is fixed to whatever you define. If you use `Range.Text` it will change with the Excel cell's number format (who ever changes it).